# Setting alarm after phone reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm, reboot

I have a problem. I am new to android and java and I'm making a program which turns off the phone sounds and dims the display at the user selected time. Everything is done by getting user input values (hour and minute) and setting the alarm based on these values to fire an intent to a BroadcastReceiver which starts a service which turns off sounds and dims the display. I want that alarm to be restarted after reboot. I thought that I can just simply set another BroadcastReceiver which receives BOOT_COMPLETED intent and then sets alarm which fires an intent to a BroadcastReceiver used before which starts the service. And my problem is that I don't know how to put the values from the activity which gets the user input to the BoradcastReceiver which is started by BOOT_COMPLETED intent. Or is there another way to set the same alarm based on the user input after reboot? In simply words I want to automatically set the alarm after reboot with the same fire time as the alarm which is set by the user. Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

The only thing you need to add is persisting it in DB or elsewhere. Every time user sets up stuff and you interact with `AlarmManager`, put it also in a file.

When you get `BOOT_COMPLETED`, load data and set all previously alarms up.

Comment: Man, I guess that's right. I just didn't think about persisting user input values to DB. Actually I save those values on SharedPreferences to get it when user closes and opens the app. Maybe it's possible to get values from SharedPreferences? Anyway, you're awesome. Big thanks!

Comment: @user2883597 Sure. `SharedPreferences` are one of the possibilities of "elsewhere".

Comment: And how do I get the value from SharedPreferences if I saved it on the main activity and I need to get the value in a BroadcastReceiver? Because every thread has its own SharedPreferences or is it one file for the entire classes in the app package?

Comment: @user2883597 Just do the same you do in `Activity`. Most probably [`SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: I think there's one problem. The BroadcastReceiver is started by an intent which comes from android system but not from my app, so the context is not the context I need. I mean in SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); I think I should use something else instead of context before calling getSharedPreferences().

Answer (score 0):

In your application's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Then implement a BroadcastReceiver to receive the broadcast:

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set the alarm here.
        }
    }
}
```

For setting alarm after reboot you can pick values of your alarm from shared preferences or from DB.