# Do something at a certain time of day in an android app

Tags: android

I'm writing a reminder app for Android where users can create custom notifications that will appear at a time of the day that they specify. I realize that there is another similar question, but the only answer was to use the AlarmManager, which, according to the documentation, resets when the device is rebooted. I want the user to be able to set a notification to appear at a certain time on a certain date, meaning that it should retain the information through a reboot.

Ultimately though, the app needs to be notified that it needs to do something.

Eventually, I would also like to have the same behavior when the device reaches a certain location, if you have any thoughts on that. :)

Bear with me, I'm a bit of a novice programmer (I'm 17).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I realize that there is another similar question, but the only answer was to use the AlarmManager`. Only one? AlarmManager is **the** way to do that. Here's an implementation which survives reboots (docs and zipped project code): https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847891/115145 and many other answers that cover `AlarmManager` and `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Answer (score 0):

The commentors are correct: you will need to use an AlarmManager to create your alarm and you will need a boot receiver to handle resetting your alarm after a reboot.

GeoLocation and GeoFences are pretty easy.  I have an example app here: https://github.com/androidfu/GeofenceExample

You're not going to care about the mock location bits in that example unless you wish to test entering and exiting your target location, but the rest of the code should work for what you need.

Also, GeoFences do not persist a reboot either so it'll be good for you to get familiar with your on-boot receiver ;)  You'll want to re-add your GeoFence after a reboot too.